# Get names of all serialized file from my Apps private directory

Tags: android

I am saving serialized objects using the current time as the filename.

The code is as follows (excluded exception handling from this code):

```
public void saveObject() {
    MyObject myobj= new MyObject(name, num);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
    String fileName = name + date;
    if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No SD card detected.Unable to Save", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
      }
      File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      out.writeObject(myobj);
      out.close();
}
```

So every time this method is called, it creates a new file with the then current time-stamp.
Now in order to un-serialze, I need to know the filename stored in the external storage directory for my app.

How do I retrieve names of all stored files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like below:

```
File list[] = getExternalFilesDir(null).listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isFile();
            }
        });
```

List will be the list of all files that stored in app's dir.